# I don't understand why my query result counts my email click wrong

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

Yes that looks better. There was still another issue. When clicking in an email it multiply the sends. This was because of the extra records in the clicks data view. I fixed it with the following query:

```
       SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN s.randomAB = '1' THEN 'A'
    WHEN s.randomAB = '2' THEN 'B'
  END AS RandomAB,
  s.identifier_moment,
  s.identifier_product,
  SUM(COUNT(s.SubscriberKey)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.identifier_moment, s.identifier_product, s.randomAB) AS TotalSent,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey) AS TotalOpens,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey) AS TotalClick
FROM [sendlog] s
LEFT JOIN [_open] o ON s.JobID = o.JobID AND s.ListID = o.ListID AND s.BatchID = o.BatchID AND s.SubID = o.SubscriberID AND o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN [_click] c ON s.JobID = c.JobID AND s.ListID = c.ListID AND s.BatchID = c.BatchID AND s.SubID = c.SubscriberID AND c.IsUnique = 1 
WHERE s.randomAB IN ('1', '2')
  AND s.identifier_moment != ''
  AND s.Datelog >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
  s.randomAB,
  s.identifier_moment,
  s.identifier_product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue could be that you are using COUNT on the SubscriberKey for both the TotalOpens and TotalClicks columns. This will count all rows in the _open and _click data views that match the join conditions, even if there are multiple opens or clicks by the same subscriber. Instead, you could try using COUNT(DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey) and COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey) to count only unique opens and clicks by each subscriber.